# Loaded image sequence flickers but only sometimes (Pygame)

Tags: python, animation, pygame

First off, I have scoured the internet (including Stack Overflow) for an answer to my seemingly simple issue, but I have not found a fix that has worked for me.  I am attempting to make a simple top down game in pygame, and all worked well until I added in a walking animation for the player. The animation is fine except that it flickers at certain points.

I have an idle animation for the player as well, but there is no flickering whatsoever. The idle animation has 2 frames, and the walking animations has 4, which brings me to suspect the problem lies within the number of frames.

Below I have pasted the code where I believe the problem lies along with this link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdsPj.jpg) to a gif of the walking animation. If a zip file with the code and images would be best, I am more than happy to provide that as well. Lastly, I am aware that some of my coding habits are not the best, such as using global variables, so I hope anyone reading through my code isn't too bothered by that. Thank you so much, it means a lot!

```
class Player:
    def drawPlayer(self):
        global playerCounter, playerWalking

        if playerWalking == "false":
            if player1Facing == "front":
                player1.loopIdle(playerIdleFrontAnim)
            if player1Facing == "back":
                player1.loopIdle(playerIdleBackAnim)
            if player1Facing == "right":
                player1.loopIdle(playerIdleRightAnim)
            if player1Facing == "left":
                player1.loopIdle(playerIdleLeftAnim)

        elif playerWalking == "true":
            if player1Facing == "front":
                player1.loopWalking(playerWalkFrontAnim)
            if player1Facing == "back":
                player1.loopWalking(playerWalkBackAnim)
            if player1Facing == "right":
                player1.loopWalking(playerWalkRightAnim)
            if player1Facing == "left":
                player1.loopWalking(playerWalkLeftAnim)

    def loopWalking(self, animation):
        global playerCounter, currentPlayerStance

        if playerCounter <= playerWalkMax:
            screen.blit(animation[0], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "upright"
        elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 2):
            screen.blit(animation[1], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "crouch"
        elif (playerCounter > (playerWalkMax * 2)) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 3):
            screen.blit(animation[2], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "upright"
        elif playerCounter > playerWalkMax * 3:
            screen.blit(animation[3], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "crouch"
            if playerCounter >= playerWalkMax * 4:
                playerCounter = 0

        playerCounter += 1

    def loopIdle(self, animation):
        global playerCounter, currentPlayerStance

        if playerCounter <= playerIdleMax:
            screen.blit(animation[0], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "upright"
        elif playerCounter > playerIdleMax:
            screen.blit(animation[1], (player1X, player1Y))
            currentPlayerStance = "crouch"
            if playerCounter >= (playerIdleMax * 2):
                playerCounter = 0

        playerCounter += 1



player1 = Player()

done = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = 1

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player1XSpeed = 0
            player1YSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if player1Facing != "left":
                    player1Facing = "left"
                player1XSpeed = -player1SpeedVal
                playerWalking = "true"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if player1Facing != "right":
                    player1Facing = "right"
                player1XSpeed = player1SpeedVal
                playerWalking = "true"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if player1Facing != "back":
                    player1Facing = "back"
                player1YSpeed = -player1SpeedVal
                playerWalking = "true"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if player1Facing != "front":
                    player1Facing = "front"
                player1YSpeed = player1SpeedVal
                playerWalking = "true"

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            playerWalking = "false"
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player1XSpeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player1YSpeed = 0

    # Update player1 movement
    player1X += player1XSpeed
    player1Y += player1YSpeed

    screen.fill(GRAY)
    if drawPlayer1 == "true":
        player1.loopWalking(playerWalkRightAnim)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please don't throw so much code at us. Try to reduce it to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post it here. Remove everything that's not related to the problem and try to isolate just the part of the code that causes the error.

Comment: @skrx alright, will do. I will guess where the problem lies

Comment: Just remove one part after the other and check if the error is still there. If it disappears you have to add the last removed part again and have an indication where the bug occurs. But don't remove so much code that we can't run the program anymore. Also, print the suspicious variables to see if they have the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're skipping some frames, 50 and 75. If `playerCounter` is 50, both of these conditions are `False` and you blit nothing.

```
elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 2):
elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax * 2) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 3):
```

You can fix the code by checking if the `playerCounter` is `<= playerWalkMax`:

```
elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax) and (playerCounter <= playerWalkMax * 2):
elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax * 2) and (playerCounter <= playerWalkMax * 3):
```

---

I used some prints to figure out which frames were skipped:

```
def loopWalking(self, animation):
    global playerCounter
    if playerCounter <= playerWalkMax:
        screen.blit(animation[0], (player1X, player1Y))
        print('blit 0', end=' ')
    elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 2):
        screen.blit(animation[1], (player1X, player1Y))
        print('blit 1', end=' ')
    elif (playerCounter > playerWalkMax * 2) and (playerCounter < playerWalkMax * 3):
        screen.blit(animation[2], (player1X, player1Y))
        print('blit 2', end=' ')
    elif playerCounter > playerWalkMax * 3:
        screen.blit(animation[3], (player1X, player1Y))
        if playerCounter >= playerWalkMax * 4:
            playerCounter = 0
        print('blit 3', end=' ')

    print(playerCounter)
    playerCounter += 1
```

Comment: Ah I completely understand. The program works wonderfully now! Thank you so much, not just for finding the problem but also for your patience and tips in the beginning :)

Comment: You're welcome! And please always try to narrow down your code in the future, so that only the problematic sections are left, but make sure that we can still run the program. That can save us lots of time and you could also find the bugs on your own in the process.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again! :)